# Decimal regex & Empty String

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal

I have this javascript Regex (3 decimal places wiht a single *dot*)

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$
```

I want to also match on an empty string `""` which i believe is

```
^$
```

How can I combine these into 1 regex

These should be the passing tests

```
"" //empty string
1
1.
1.0
1.00
1.000
123456789
0
.0
.00
.000
```

I hope I have covered all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digit period case was a difficult one, that my original answer missed.  This answer is simpler than the others, covers all cases, and doesn't have any false matches.

- Start of the string
- Match Either

  - digits 1+ times then optional "."
  - "." as long as there is a digit ahead
- digits 0-3 times
- end of string

**Expression**

```
^((\d+\.?|\.(?=\d))?\d{0,3})$
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/ruwkiv)

Comment: That doens't match "1." or "123456789"

Answer (score 3):

Not including the empty space, your current expression doesn't seem to pass your requirements.

```
^\d*\.?\d{0,3}$
```

Optional leading digits, optional point, up to three more digits before the end.

EDIT:
@Guffa noticed that my original solution would also match simply a dot, "."

```
^\d*((\d\.)|(\.\d))?\d{0,3}$
```

This version replaces the `\.?` check with a check for a digit followed by a dot, or a dot followed by a digit, or neither.

Comment: Beat me to the answer by 0.1 secs +1

Comment: The string `"."` will also pass that test.

Comment: Just needed to `^\d*((\d\.)|(\.\d))?\d{0,2}$` change 3 > 2 as well

Comment: This answer is not correct.  The method chosen could validate a number with four digits in the nths place.  For example:  `.1234`.  If you changed to `\d{0,2}` then it would not match `1.234` which is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Make an expression with three different cases:

- zero or more digits
- one or more digits, period, zero to three digits
- zero or more digits, period, one to three digits

This will pass all your tests, and also the string `"."` will not pass:

```
^(\d*|\d+\.\d{0,3}|\d*\.\d{1,3})$
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9pnwk/

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go for a ==="" or your regex comparison, just for performance's sake